# Comparar dos variables de tipo char en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código con el problema en la línea 101, necesito comparar dos char y no lo consigo. Realmente me interesa es comparar el carácter inicial de la lista jugadorUno y luego con el jugadorDos por lo que pensé que sería bueno pasar de string a char pero no puedo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Uno
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> jugadorUno = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> jugadorDos = new ArrayList<String>();

        int totalUno = 0;
        int totalDos = 0;
    
        System.out.println("Introducir letra: ");
        //String letra = leer.nextLine();
        char letra = leer.next().charAt(0);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            String palabra = "";
            int condicion = 0;


            System.out.println("Escriba 'salir' para terminar de escribir palabras");
            System.out.println("Jugador " + (i+1) + " ingrese palabras:");

            if (i == 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    palabra = leer.nextLine();

                    if (palabra.equalsIgnoreCase("Salir"))
                    {
                        condicion = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jugadorUno.add(palabra);
                    } 
                
                } while(condicion != 1);
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                palabra = leer.nextLine();

                    if (palabra.equalsIgnoreCase("Salir"))
                    {
                        condicion = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jugadorDos.add(palabra);
                    }
                 
                } while(condicion != 1);
            }
        
        }
    
        // comprueba palabras repetidas en ambas listas
        for(String uno : jugadorUno)
        {
            for(String dos : jugadorDos)
            {
                if (uno.equalsIgnoreCase(dos))
                {
                    totalUno += 5;
                    totalDos += 5;
                }
            
            }
        }

        // Comprueba si la palabra inicia por la letra correspondiente
        for(String uno : jugadorUno)
        {
            //uno.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(uno);
            char aux = uno.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(aux);
            if (aux == letra)
            {
                totalUno += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                totalUno -= 7;
            }
        }

        /*
        for(String dos : jugadorDos)
        {
            String aux = dos.charAt(0);
            if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase(letra))
            {
            totalDos += 10;
            
            }
            else
            {
                totalDos -= 7;
            }    
        }
        */  
    
        /*
        System.out.print("[");
        for(String str : jugadorUno)
        {
            System.out.print(str +", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
        */

        System.out.println(jugadorUno + " - " +  totalUno);
        System.out.println(jugadorDos + " - " + totalDos);

    }
}
```

El caso es que  por alguna razón me sale el error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> String index out of range: 0
> at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
> at Uno.main(Uno.java:101)

He buscado e intentado implementar la manera correcta pero aún no consigo hacer que funcione

Comment: Y cual seria la linea 101?

Comment: Por favor, lee como hacer un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede simplificar el código pero bueno a lo que indicas, tendrás que cambiar estas líneas.

**String letra = leer.nextLine();** //descomenta esta linea

**char letra1 = letra.toString().charAt(0);** //cambia de nombre a letra1 o como le quieras llamar para no tener error con la variable letra

**if (aux == letra1)** //Cambia la variable letra por letra1 o el nombre que le hayas indicado

Este sería tu código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Uno
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> jugadorUno = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> jugadorDos = new ArrayList<String>();

        int totalUno = 0;
        int totalDos = 0;
    
        System.out.println("Introducir letra: ");
        String letra = leer.nextLine(); //descomenta esta linea
        char letra1 = letra.toString().charAt(0); //cambia de nombre a letra1 para no tener error con la variable letra

    
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            String palabra = "";
            int condicion = 0;


            System.out.println("Escriba 'salir' para terminar de escribir palabras");
            System.out.println("Jugador " + (i+1) + " ingrese palabras:");

            if (i == 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    palabra = leer.nextLine();

                    if (palabra.equalsIgnoreCase("Salir"))
                    {
                        condicion = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jugadorUno.add(palabra);
                    } 
                
                } while(condicion != 1);
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                palabra = leer.nextLine();

                    if (palabra.equalsIgnoreCase("Salir"))
                    {
                        condicion = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jugadorDos.add(palabra);
                    }
                 
                } while(condicion != 1);
            }
        
        }
    
        // comprueba palabras repetidas en ambas listas
        for(String uno : jugadorUno)
        {
            for(String dos : jugadorDos)
            {
                if (uno.equalsIgnoreCase(dos))
                {
                    totalUno += 5;
                    totalDos += 5;
                }
            
            }
        }

        // Comprueba si la palabra inicia por la letra correspondiente
        for(String uno : jugadorUno)
        {
            //uno.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(uno);
            char aux = uno.charAt(0);
            System.out.print(aux);
            if (aux == letra1) //Cambia la variable letra por letra1
            {
                totalUno += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                totalUno -= 7;
            }
        }

        /*
        for(String dos : jugadorDos)
        {
            String aux = dos.charAt(0);
            if (aux.equalsIgnoreCase(letra))
            {
            totalDos += 10;
            
            }
            else
            {
                totalDos -= 7;
            }    
        }
        */  
    
        /*
        System.out.print("[");
        for(String str : jugadorUno)
        {
            System.out.print(str +", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
        */

        System.out.println(jugadorUno + " - " +  totalUno);
        System.out.println(jugadorDos + " - " + totalDos);

    }
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).Que fue lo que arreglaste? si no, no queda claro cual era el problema, porque se daba y cual es la solucion...

Comment: Sinceramente no entendí el porqué del fallo pero soy nuevo en java y aún no estoy muy al corriente, sin embargo, me salvaste de un apuro así que te agradezco totalmente, cuando tenga algo de tiempo me pongo a detallar el código para ver los fallos.

Comment: El fallo viene por que estas asignando leer.next().charAt(0);   Esto es un error ya que el metodo next devuelve un Objeto de tipo Stirng pero no el valor de ese objeto. por eso te puse la linea  "String letra = leer.nextLine()" para que primero se asigne a un objeto String y luego con el método toSring "letra.toString()" obtengas el valor de ese string y puedas usar el método charAt.